# Button with other components inside

Tags: android, button, custom-component

I would like to create custom component in Android Studio. This should be a button but with other components like ImageView or ChceckBox inside. How to do this?

I'm already tried create a Compound Control (LinearView with components inside) but I can't set onClickListener to catch click event of this and it's not so elegant solution.

I would like to avoid creating my own component nearly from scratch (extend View and override onDraw method) but I don't know how I can do this in other way.

Comment: "I can't set onClickListener to catch click event of this" -- why not? `setOnClickListener()` exists, and it works. You do need to mark the container as being clickable (e.g., `android:clickable="true"` in a layout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) to achieve view over/inside another view, **something like this:**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[10]" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="check"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**This will look like this:**

[image]

And about your click listeners - if you want to do the same thing when any of your views are clicked just add a click listener to your parent layout.

If you want to do different things for different view clicks with `ConstraintLayout` you can simply attach click listener for every view that you have.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want